Page Style No header Yes Footer
I need a \pagestyle{} like plain style, but in this case I don´t want header but I do need Footer because I don't want the line in the header.
I tried with
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot{\leavevmode\rlap{\parbox[t]{\textwidth}{\tiny\color{gray} \textcopyright SOME TEXT}}
\hfill}

But I still having the line in the header.

Could you provide a fill compilable example? I.e. provide everything in your document from \documentclass{} (the very first line of your code) to \end{document} (your last line of code). If you have some irrelevant stuff to your problem in between \begin{document} and \end{document} you can exclude that. This makes it easier to help solve your problem:)

The fancyfoot command seems overly complicated... What are you trying to obtain?

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}


In order to remove the header, you can simply set its rulewidth to 0 using \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} in the preamble. I added some generated text to showcase a real document example:

I also managed to guess which package I was missing in order to run your code snippet without problems (It was xcolor). Here's the MWE (minimum working example) constructed using your code along with a little suggestion:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum} % Used to insert text

\usepackage{xcolor} % Used for color

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % <-- Shorter alternative to \fancyhead{}\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot{\leavevmode\rlap{\parbox[t]{\textwidth}{\tiny\color{gray} \textcopyright SOME TEXT}}\hfill}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % <-- Clears the header


\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-5] % Some text

\newpage

\lipsum[1-4] % Some more text

\end{document}

Lastly, if you want further details, I suggest you read this answer about removing headers.
